# Extension by continuity of $\frac{x-n \pi}{\sin(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, continuity

I read that the function
$$
\frac{x-n \pi}{\sin(x)}
$$
is of class $C^{\infty}$ on a neighborhood of $n \pi$. What is meant ? Is that true ? It seems to me like this function can't be continuously extended at an $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that it stays of class $C^{\infty}$...

Comment: Consider just the case $n=0$ and then the reciprocal, for which you can even write down the Taylor series (so the function is even *analytic* in a neighbourhood odf $0$, not merely $C^\infty$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true (more than $C^\infty$, the function is analytic).

Consider how the sine behaves near $n\pi$:

$$\begin{align}
\sin x &= \sin (n\pi + (x-n\pi))\\
&= (-1)^n\sin (x-n\pi)\\
&= (-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}(x-n\pi)^{2k+1}.
\end{align}$$

Then it is evident that dividing that by $x-n\pi$ yields a convergent power series, whence

$$g_n(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x-n\pi} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+k}}{(2k+1)!}(x-n\pi)^{2k}$$

is, with the value $g_n(n\pi) = (-1)^n$, an infinitely differentiable function. $g_n$ is nonzero in a neighbourhood of $n\pi$ - the closest zeros are $(n-1)\pi$ and $(n+1)\pi$ - and therefore

$$\frac{1}{g_n(x)} = \frac{x-n\pi}{\sin x}$$

is smooth (even analytic) in a neighbourhood of $n\pi$.

Comment: What to say ? You make it look so easy. Once again, thank you very much, merci !

Comment: Decades of experience help ;)